# VScode Mac Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Mac with Catalina installed and the latest version now reports this error:

> Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.

This happens when i try to open `Git - View History` tab.

How can this be resolved?

---

##### Version

[image]

On a side note, i saw some older issues with suggestions to load code with --no-sandbox which does not imply to my case (implies only to Windows users i think)

Answer (score 11):

Try to terminate VScode in activity monitor and re-run it.
In most cases, the problem is related to an instance (VScode app or updater) running in background.

Comment: This solved it for me. In the Task Manager (Windows) I could see a process of VS Code utilising about 20 % of the CPU, even though VS Code was already closed. Once I killed that process and started VS Code again, the problem was gone.

Comment: Worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04).

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by restarting my MacBook. After restarting, all my extension pages load again. Perhaps is something related to M1 chip.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Updating that a reboot solved this issue for me :| .

Comment: Unclear if this is a comment or the solution to the problem. It's best to mark one of the responses as an answer and then providing this as a comment to that response. Unless you have a significantly different answer that the ones provided; in that case mark this as the answer as such.